# Como capturar uma NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net, nullpointerexception

Quando testo minha aplicação, ela retorna alguns dados específicos, porém quando o dado solicitado é nulo, aparece este erro de exceção não tratada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer uma captura dele mas acho que estou errando.
Como posso deixar um tratamento que avise em uma textbox que o dado solicitado não foi encontrado?

```
'Buscar informações via GoogleBook API (precisa ser arrumado)'
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Step 1:- google API url responsible for returning the book detail in JASON format'
    Const GOOGLEAPIURL As String = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="

    If Me.txtISBN.Text <> String.Empty Then
        Dim requestURL As String

        'Step 2:- Reformed the URL to target particular ISBN number'
        requestURL = GOOGLEAPIURL + Me.txtISBN.Text.Trim() + "+isbn"

        'Step 3: created Http webrequest for URL'
        Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURL)
        'Step4 : get the response of web request in http web response object'
        Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = wr.GetResponse()

        'Step 5: passes the response stream in stream reader'
        Dim sreader As New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
        'Step 6: parsing the reader(which is in Jason format) using JASON.NET'

        Dim rss = JObject.Parse(sreader.ReadToEnd())

        'Step 7: if object find the fetch the detail'

        If rss Is Nothing = False AndAlso rss.Count > 0 Then
            Me.lblBookName.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("title").ToString()
            Me.lblSubtitle.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("subtitle").ToString()
            Me.lblAuthor.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("authors").ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").ToString()
            Me.lblPublisher.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("publisher").ToString()
            Me.lblPublishedDate.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("publishedDate").ToString()
            Me.lblPageCount.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("pageCount").ToString()

            'Captura de erro'
            Try
                rss = True
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("Nada aqui")
        End If
    Else

        Me.lblMessage.Text = "Please enter the ISBN number"
    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, reforçando o que o @Maniero disse

> Por favor, nunca use um `try-catch` se não tiver certeza do que está fazendo. Ele não é solução, ele é aumento de problema.

Pelo que eu entendi e consegui ver do código, você está tentando pegar os dados de um JSON e jogar em `TextBoxes`. O que está acontecendo é que estás tentando acessar algum elemento que não existe no JSON. Como você não tem como mudar a resposta que estás recebendo da API, vais precisar validar se os dados/elementos realmente existem no JSON antes de tentar acessá-los.

<sub>Eu não sei muito bem como funciona em VB.NET e como tua questão tem a *tag* C#, primeiramente vou responder em C# e depois edito a resposta para colocar o código em VB.NET.</sub>

```
if(rss.Item("items")[0] != null && rss.Item("items")[0].Item("volumeInfo") != null)
{
    if(rss.Item("items")[0].Item("volumeInfo").Item("subtitle") != null)
        lblBookName.Text = rss.Item("items")[0].Item("volumeInfo").Item("subtitle").ToString();
    else
        lblBookName.Text = "Dado não encontrado";
}
```

Essa talvez não seja a melhor forma de validar isso. Particularmente eu salvaria `rss.Item("items")[0].Item("volumeInfo")` numa variável e usaria ela para verificar se os itens dentro dela estão nulos ou não. Mas isso é questão de gosto e o importante é tu poder entender que **a solução não é usar `try-catch`**, você só precisa verificar se os elementos existem antes de tentar acessá-los.

Comment: Poxa valeu @jbueno, consegui! Com esse trecho do seu código, adaptei para o VS e funcionou!!

Ficou assim:
`código`
   If Me.lblPublisher.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("publisher") = True Then
                    Me.lblPublisher.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("publisher").ToString()
                Else
                    lblPublisher.Text = "dado não encontrado"
                End If
`código`

não editar pra por o codigo aqui ¬¬

Answer (score 8):

Isto é um erro de programação portanto não deve capturar exceção alguma. Fazer isto seria tentar jogar a sujeira embaixo do tapete. Este erro não é normal, é é o sintoma de que há algo errado no código e a solução é consertar o erro.

Como não há detalhes não posso dizer qual é a solução exata mas em linhas gerais o que deve ser feito é evitar que está exceção seja lançada. Ou seja, deve verificar se a variável que está nula é nula antes de tentar acessá-la. Não pode acessar um valor nulo, simples assim.

Qualquer outra solução que tente será gambiarra produzirá um código ruim.

E por favor, nunca use um `try-catch` se não tiver certeza do que está fazendo. Ele não é solução, ele é aumento de problema.

Comment: Então, minha intenção era capturar a exceção e continuar a execução do block try para obter os dados restantes, eu sei que isso não é nao é boa prática, mas eu teria razões plausíveis para explicar o pq....

Comment: Se você tivesse, teria explicado. Isto não faz nenhum sentido em nenhuma circunstância que eu conheço. O `try-catch` que você usou é provavelmente é o mais esdrúxulo que eu já vi.

Comment: teria explicado aqui na pergunta ou comentado no codigo? enfim... é o método que achei para não parar a execução do programa, coloquei apenas uma MsgBox avisando sobre dados que não foram encontrados.
Por isso vim perguntar sobre qual outro método que poderia esta utilizando... :/

Comment: Acho que você não leu minha resposta. O programa está parando por um erro de programação. Você tem que consertá-lo e não deixar parar. Você quer jogar a sujeira pra baixo do tapete, isto não resolve nada. O método é verificar (`if``) se a informação está presente. Se ela não está, você informa o usuário desta situação, mas não deixa o programa gerar uma exceção. Se quiser aprender sobre exceções, eu escrevi bastante sobre isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+%5Bexceção%5D

Comment: entendi, acabei interpretando mal, mas obrigado assim mesmo. Consegui resolver com o trecho adaptado que o @jbueno me passou, e entendi agora o que quis dizer sobre jogar para debaixo do tapete rsrs . Vlw mesmo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Após olhar o trecho que o @jbueno me passou, adaptei para usa-lo no VS e obtive o resultado esperado!

```
   If Me.lblPublisher.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("publisher") = True Then
                Me.lblPublisher.Text = rss.Item("items")(0).Item("volumeInfo").Item("publisher").ToString()
            Else
                lblPublisher.Text = "dado não encontrado"
            End If
```

Com isso deixei de usar o Try Catch (já que minha intenção era ignorar NullReferenceException) e consegui dar continuidade na execução do programa sem deixar qualquer problema no código e ainda informando ao usuário sobre qual dado não pode ter sido localizado!

Obrigado :D